# How to get substr not striped value in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I want to get `Example` as output after removing `&lt;br&gt;` How can I get it?

```js
console.log('Example&lt;br&gt;'.substr('Example&lt;br&gt;'.length - 10))
```

Answer (score 2):

From MDN [`String.prototype.substr()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr)

> Warning: Although String.prototype.substr(…) is not strictly deprecated (as in "removed from the Web standards"), it is defined in Annex B of the ECMA-262 standard, whose introduction states:
>
> ---
>
> All of the language features and behaviours specified in this annex have one or more undesirable characteristics and in the absence of legacy usage would be removed from this specification. …
>   … Programmers should not use or assume the existence of these features and behaviours when writing new ECMAScript code. …

You can use [`String.prototype.substring()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) instead. You have to pass the start and end position to the function.

> The substring() method returns the part of the string between the start and end indexes, or to the end of the string.

```js
console.log('Example&lt;br&gt;'.substring(0, 'Example&lt;br&gt;'.length - 10))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this way

```js
console.log('Example&lt;br&gt;'.substr(0, 7));

// OR

console.log('Example&lt;br&gt;'.split('&lt;br&gt;')[0]);
```

Answer (score 1):

To strictly answer your question you can do this:

```js
console.log('Example&lt;br&gt;'.substr(0,'Example&lt;br&gt;'.length - 10));
```

The `substr()` function can take 2 parameters, the first is the starting index, the second is optional and it's the number of characters you want to extract. You were missing a 0 as the starting index. Documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr).

Answer (score 0):

Shah, it appears that you are parsing a server response that did not decode HTML elements before returning them to the client. If you cannot control the server response, the following alternative will let you deal with any HTML tags that might be included:

```
var elem = document.createElement('textarea');
elem.innerHTML = 'Example&lt;br&gt;';
var decoded = elem.value;
alert(decoded.replace(/<(?:.|\n)*?>/gm, ''));
```

Answer (score 0):

Shah, it appears that you are parsing a server response that did not decode HTML elements before returning them to the client. If you cannot control the server response, the following alternative will let you deal with any HTML tags that might be included:

```
var elem = document.createElement('textarea');
elem.innerHTML = 'Example&lt;br&gt;';
var decoded = elem.value;
console.log(decoded.replace(/<(?:.|\n)*?>/gm, ''));
```